# What address should I use for SPF Record in Amazon Workmail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, spf, amazon-workmail

I have an email config where emails are hosted by Amazon Workmail. I also manage the domain's DNS entries.

I want to configure an SPF TXT Record for my domain to indicate that only Amazon Workmail Servers are authorized to send emails on behalf of the domain.

The [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/adminguide/authenticate_domain.html) suggests referring to a guide on configuring SPF with SES where the following record is shown at the bottom of the page:-

`"v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ~all"`

However, I am not sure that the address `amazonses.com` is the same address that is used for Workmail. Does workmail have its own address or does it share the same as Amazon SES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workspace service, will be [using the SES service to provide email](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/adminguide/what_is.html#related_services) sending functionality, this is why you would in SPF use `amazonses.com`.

> Amazon WorkMail uses Amazon SES to send all outgoing email. The test mail domain and your domains are available for management in the Amazon SES console.